# Are there generic Python libraries that provide 'signals' (event) capability like Django signals?

Tags: python, events, python-2.7, signals

I'd like to use something like [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) in non-Django projects.  I thought I'd seen libraries like this in the past, but I've been unable to locate one via the usual searches.

[Python's signal library](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) doesn't offer the same capabilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of modules for this. Here are a few options, ordered by what I think their popularity is:

- The [blinker](https://github.com/jek/blinker/) module provides a signal/event mechanism
- [PyDispatcher](http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/) gives you event dispatch
- The [PySignals](https://github.com/theojulienne/PySignals) module is the Django signals module without any dependency on Django
- [SpiffSignal](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpiffSignal/0.1.0) implements a signal/event framework, but its GitHub page seems to be missing

Comment: Django currently [uses PyDispatcher under the hoods](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Signals)